# Dopesheet selecting multiple objects at once

Tags: keyframes, selection-tools, dopesheet

So I have 7 objects that are all moving in unsion, but I need them to animate one after another. The problem is that when I am trying to select them in the dopesheet, no matter what I do, every single one of them is selected at once.

Here's a picture of what I've got right now:
[image: rip dopesheet]

I've tried doing many things to stop them from being all selected, including the `show only selected` filter.

The objects were seperated in edit mode, which may have something to do with it.

Comment: If you separated objects after they were animated then they will share the same animation, which will be shown in the Dopesheet.

Comment: Okay, but is there a way to make it so that when I select one it doesn't select them all?